# Is a resource under a non-singular resource still RESTful?

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

Oftentimes when looking to design a REST API I see a common pattern of `/resourceA/{id}/resourceThatBelongsToA`.

Is it ok to do `/resourceA/resourcesThatBelongToA` when designing an API?

#### Reallife example

Say I have a web application similar to StackOverflow. There are questions, and each question has a status of `accepted` or `not accepted`.

I expose an endpoint `/questions/{id}/status` so that users can determine whether or not a question has an accepted answer.

I then run into the problem of wanting to discover all questions that have an accepted answer. I then define an endpoint `/questions/statuses?status=accepted`. This endpoint, when given no query parameters, will list all the statuses of all questions (with reasonable limits on the amount of statuses return, say 100). However, when given a filter of status type, I can determine all questions that have an answer that was accepted.

To me, this seems like a practical design that fits the use case well.

Is this an acceptable pattern to use or is there something more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to do /resourceA/resourcesThatBelongToA when designing an API?

Yes.

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.
REST doesn't care how you organize your resource hierarchy.

> Is this an acceptable pattern to use or is there something more suitable?

The heuristic I recommend is "would you do it this way with a web site?"  If the answer is yes, then you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

REST APIs look good when you have a unique id for the parent resource you are dealing with. `/questions/{id}` is good if you want to get the question resource with the particular id. But if you don't have a unique ID and if the response is going to be a set of resources, then it is just a filter applied to the parent resource.

So for your case, the API can be

```
/questions?status=accepted
```

If you want the api consumers to get the flexibility for choosing limits, you can use a query parameter **limit** for it.

```
/questions?status=accepted&limit=10
```